# Chromium DocumentRoot browsing file://

Tags: local, chromium, document-root

I'm looking for a way to set the DocumentRoot while browsing local file:// sites.
My situation:
I have a copy of my web server on my local machine and sync it via rsync to the server. I'm looking for a way to check these site (while offline, so I can't just sync them) without installing a local web server.
I can open the files, but all links beginning at the DocumentRoot are broken.
What I'm looking for:
A switch like "chromium --doc-root=/home/user/website/http/" or similar would be perfect.
Is there anything like this?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, I don't think Chromium provides such options to specify document root for file scheme, which is also obey the file URI scheme (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme).

For your case, I think it's better to use a simple http server (e.g. if you have python, just use `SimpleHTTPServer`). 
Ff file scheme is used, you still have to append `--allow-file-access-from-files` to avoid permission restrictions.

Comment: I was afraid this would be the case... Thanks for the tip (SimpleHTTPServer).